# Mapping class with id and collection without creating table

Tags: nhibernate

I would like to map in NHibernate such class but without creating table for parent class.

```
public class CarService
{
    public Guid CarId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Service> Services { get; protected set; }

    public void Add(Service service)
    {
        if (this.Services.Any(s => s.Type == service.Type))
        {
            throw new Exception("service type already added");
        }

        this.Services.Add(service);
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }

    public ServiceType Type { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

So I would like to have only one table for Child that would be look like:

```
| CHILD    |
|----------|
| ChildId  |
| ParentId | 
| Prop1    |
| Prop2    |
| ...      |
|----------|
```

Is it possible to do such mapping in NHibernate?

EDIT:
I've updated my object model. The main reason to have that parent class it to have something that will protect integration of my model (aggregate root from DDD). In my model I have class CarService that will store all services bought for car I want to create some validation in my model that will prevent to add the same service type twice.

Comment: It is possible, but honestly would there be any benefit? If you explain it more, what you'd like to achieve I can show you some tricks. But I would not like show something just because it is possible, would like to understand what is the purpose behind... because maybe we can find better solution... just if you want ;)

Comment: Hi @RadimKöhler - I've provided more details about my case

Comment: If I get your requirement... you should for sure observe http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events. These are interceptors and events, into which you can hook on. They are really awesome, because based on the ParentId, you can create a Parent in a runtime. E.g. OnLoad event... But honestly, I would go the way having the Parent table as well. Even as a "mimic" of the model completenes (constraint on ParentID is good reason) then you can still have your Parent objects with powerful implementation, but you will profit form NHibernate istantiating them... does it help?

Comment: Thank you @RadimKöhler - your answer help me a lot. I don't have any problem with table with only one column, but DBA, Analysts and others that work only with DB have that problem.

Comment: As I tried to express: we can do that;) but in fact, if they are smart DB guys, they should like the foreing keys and contstraint values in ParentId. So, Please, do not give up... and try to repreoduce the battle... maybe you win ;) anyhow, with interceptors you can achieve that... for sure ;) ENjoy NHibernate ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You can always construct the Parent object in-memory, but NHibernate will not do it for you.